# Solidity inheritance: how can I access variables in inherited contracts?

Tags: inheritance, multiple-inheritance, solidity

I have contract Car, inheriting from BasicData and Ownership.
When a Car is transferred to a new owner, I want to emit an event.
In that event, I need to pass the ID of the car in that event for logging purposes.

```
contract Car is BasicData, Ownership
{
  // does all kinds of stuff
}
```

_

```
contract BasicData
{
  uint public _id;
  // etc
}
```

_

```
contract Ownership
{
  address owner;

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    owner = newOwner;
    emit Update("Contract with ID changed owner", _id, newOwner)
  }
}
```

How can I access `_id` in the `transferOwnership` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `_id` in `Ownership`, because it has no such state variable and doesn't inherit from anything.

You could access `_id` in `Car`, because it *does* inherit from something that declares that variable (`BasicData`).

A possible fix would be to have `Ownership` inherit from `BasicData`. (Then `Car` could inherit from just `Ownership`.)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I could somehow retrieve it from a call like `car.transferOwnership(0x...)` (through trying to get the callee f.i.)